# Testing a command's stored exit status with var=$?; [[ $var ]] is always true, whether 0 or 1

Tags: bash, function, return

Consider:

```
true; run_backup=$?
if [[ $run_backup ]]; then
  echo "The user wants to run the backup"
fi
```

...and...

```
false; run_backup=$?
if [[ $run_backup ]]; then
  echo "The user wants to run the backup"
fi
```

`The user wants to run the backup` is emitted whether `run_backup` has 0 (success) or 1 (false)!

What's going on here?

(My real command, instead of `true` or `false`, is of the form `zenity --question --text "..."`).

Comment: Please build a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible** code that demonstrates a problem when run without changes. Anything/everything unessential to showcasing the specific problematic behavior should be removed before posting.

Comment: That is to say -- why is `zenity` in the question? And do make sure your code still *actually works* to demonstrate the bug; an empty function with no body is a syntax error, so this code *definitely doesn't* work; someone who tries to run it will get an error other than the one you're trying to show us.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You have to scroll, but `RUN_BACKUP` is the exit status of `zenity`.

Comment: I would prefer to see the description edited to reference the actual function names and conditionals of interest; as is ... 'a conditional', 'another conditional', 'forcing the conditional', 'calls a function', 'call another function', 'moves to next function' ... isn't much help if I'm having to guess at mapping these generic terms to the sample code

Comment: @chepner, ...sure, but I don't see any valid reason for the question to *actually include zenity*. Hardcoding `RUN_BACKUP=0` will make a reproducer people without zenity can test (and if it *didn't*, the OP could narrow the question down to only be about zenity and nothing else).

Comment: I can't very well clarify anything because my original question and code are no longer there.  Other than to say that two options to exit that zenity dialogue return null and not null, which is why the conditional was in the form it was.  I tested that conditional pretty thoroughly, it worked.  What failed was that when the end of the function was reached, instead of returning to the line after the function was called, the script proceeded to the function which followed.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ $run_backup ]]` is not a Boolean check; it fails only if its argument is an empty string (which neither 0 nor 1 is).

Since `zenity` returns 0 if you click OK, you want something like

```
[[ $run_backup -eq 0 ]] && echo "The user wants to run the backup"
```

or

```
(( run_backup == 0 )) && echo "The user wants to run the backup"
```

or

```
# You need to negate the value because success(0)/failure(!=0) use
# the opposite convention of true(1)/false(0)
(( ! run_backup )) && echo "The user wants to run the backup"
```

---

Based on the fact that `run_backup` was the exit status of a `zenity` command in the original question, the simplest thing would be to simply use `&&` to combine `zenity` and your function into one command.

```
zenity --question --width=300 --text "..." && echo "The user wants to run the backup"
```

Comment: I've edited the question to be narrowly focused on the OP's underlying misapprehension about bash-the-language, since a good duplicate was being hard-to-find; hopefully doing so didn't disrupt this answer too much.

Comment: If you hit cancel zenity returns null, which was why the conditional was in the format it was in.  However using the exit code that was is not something I had thought of.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes, because neither 0 nor 1 is NULL.

Comment: `[[ NULL ]]` will exit with success also