# bash true and false don't work as expected

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, return-value

I have this script saved as `truefalse.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n " 'true' returns "
true
if [ $? ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
echo -n "'false' returns "
false
if [ $? ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi

echo

echo -n " 'true' returns "
if [ $(true) ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
echo -n "'false' returns "
if [ $(false) ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

The results are not what I expected:

```
$ truefalse.sh
 'true' returns true
'false' returns true

 'true' returns false
'false' returns false
```

In both cases, I would have expected `true` to return "true" and `false` to return "false" based on my understanding of `$?`, `$(*command*)`, `man true` and `man false`

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT**

Based on the answers at [Testing a command's stored exit status with var=$?; [[ $var ]] is always true, whether 0 or 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418286/testing-a-commands-stored-exit-status-with-var-var-is-always-true-w), I changed my script, thinking the `[` and `]` brackets were what's responsible for the return code being interpreted as a string value:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n " 'true' returns "
true
if $?; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
echo -n "'false' returns "
false
if $?; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi

echo

echo -n " 'true' returns "
if ${true}; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
echo -n "'false' returns "
if ${false}; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi

echo

 true && echo true || echo false
false && echo true || echo false
```

The changed results for the first block look plausibile, but why are the results from the second block inverted?

```
$ truefalse.sh
 'true' returns truefalse.sh: line 4: 0: command not found
false
'false' returns truefalse.sh: line 11: 1: command not found
false

 'true' returns true
'false' returns true

true
false
```

Comment: `[ $? ]` checks whether `$?` is a non-empty string. Both `0` and `1` are non-empty, so both of them are truth-y when evaluated in that way.

Comment: Don't use `if [ $? ]` at all. Just use `if true; then ...` or `if false; then ...` in the common case. There's rarely a good reason to use `$?` unless you want to check whether an exit status is in a specific range (say, exactly either `0` or `2`).

Comment: `[ $? ]` returns true unless `$?` expands to an empty string or a string merely consisting of spaces. And that, unless IFS is changed, never happens.

Comment: @oguzismail, ...well, someone could run `IFS=0`, and _that_ would make `$?` evaluate as empty when not quoted and having a value of 0. :)

Comment: @FKEinternet, ...and in the uncommon cases, consider something like `if (( $? == 0 || $? == 2 )); then` to use an arithmetic context.

Comment: @Charles right :D I never learned how IFS affects word splitting and other stuff completely